# How to apply blur to image and then cache it with Kingfisher?

Tags: swift, kingfisher

I am trying to download an image from a `URL`, blur it, cache it and then display it in a table view cell.

I did this:

```
let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: recipe.uid)
backgroundImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource)
backgroundImageView.image = backgroundImageView.image?.kf.blurred(withRadius: CGFloat(7.6))
```

but this means that I would blur the image after setting it to the image view which is not want I want.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Found the solution:**

```
let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: url, cacheKey: recipe.uid)
let processor = BlurImageProcessor(blurRadius: 4)
backgroundImageView.kf.setImage(with: resource, placeholder: nil, options: [.processor(processor)], progressBlock: nil, completionHandler: nil)
```